# Proof the probability of a collision for a hash function

Tags: hashing

I don't know how to prove the following:

Let $a$ be randomly chosen out of $\{ 1,..., p-1\}$ and $b$ randomly chosen out of $\{ 0,..., p-1\}$.
Let $m$ be a natural number smaller than a prime number $p$. Let $ h_{a,b}:$ $\{ 0,..., p-1\} \to \{0, ..., m-1 \}$ which is defined as  $ h_{a,b} = (ax + b \mod p) \mod m$. Prove for all natural numbers $x, y$ with $x < y < p$:
$ P_{a,b}(h_{a,b}(x)=h_{a,b}(y)) \le \frac{1}{m}$ where $P$ is the probability.

Comment: When asking a question like this, I encourage you to provide additional context, such as: Where did you encounter this task?  What did you try, and what progress have you made?  If you're stuck, working through a few examples with small numbers (e.g., with $p=3$ or $p=5$) is often useful for developing intuition.

Answer (score -1):

Let $k_{a,b}(x) = ax + b \bmod{p}$. If $x \neq y$ then $k_{a,b}(x), k_{a,b}(y)$ is a random pair of distinct numbers in $\{0,\ldots,p-1\}$. Therefore we have reduced your question into the following one:

> Show that if $x \neq y$ are random distinct numbers in $\{0,\ldots,p-1\}$, then $$\Pr[x \bmod m = y \bmod m] \leq \frac{1}{m}.$$

Suppose that $p = dm + r$, where $1 \leq r \leq m-1$. Then $\Pr[x \bmod m = c]$ is either $d/p$ (for $c \ge r$) or $(d+1)/p$ (for $c < r$). It follows that
$$
\Pr[x \bmod m = y \bmod m] =  r \frac{(d+1)d}{p(p-1)} + (m-r) \frac{d(d-1)}{p(p-1)} = \frac{(p-m+r)d}{p(p-1)}.
$$
Since $r < m$, we have $\frac{p-m+r}{p-1} \leq 1$. Also, $\frac{d}{p} \leq \frac{d}{dm} = \frac{1}{m}$. Altogether, we obtain an upper bound of $\frac{1}{m}$.

Comment: Why is the probabillity for $\Pr[x \bmod m = c]$  either $d/p$ (for $c \ge r$) or $(d+1)/p$ (for $c < r$)?

Comment: And as a follow up question, shouldn't it be $m > r$ at the end because of the way you defined $r$?

Comment: Right, thanks for the correction. As for calculating the probability that $x \bmod m = c$, you'll have to work it out. Perhaps try some concrete numerical examples.